# CodeFluent persistence race condition

Tags: codefluent

As soon as the database becomes slow for some reason ( long running query, backup, performance analyzer)

My Web Application start getting, eventually the following errors:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.InternalExecuteNonQuery(Boolean firstTry)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.InternalExecuteNonQuery(Boolean firstTry)
.... _> stack trace continues to my code


CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentRuntimeException: CF1044: Nested persistence command is not supported. Current command: '[Contract_Search]', nested command: '[zref_template_document_LoadBlobFile]'.
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(String schema, String package, String intraPackageName, String name)
   at CodeFluent.Runtime.BinaryServices.BinaryLargeObject.GetInputStream(CodeFluentContext context, Int64 rangeStart, Int64 rangeEnd)
.... _> stack trace continues to my code
```

The second error `CF1044` happens when I open two browser windows and doing different actions. Search in one, generate a document in another.

It's difficult to reproduce. It never happens the same way.

There is a **race condition** somewhere I can't figure out.

Comment: Actually I've got this kind of regression after disabling BinaryServices cache.

Comment: Also I have migrated the most of my binary content to filesystem. Currently I have most of blob configured to use filesystem, but few are still in the database.

Comment: Do you use `GetInputStream()` directly in your code? If so, you may need to call the complete command after using the stream: `customer.Photo.ConfigurationContext.Persistence.CompleteCommand(true)`.

Comment: Yes I do use `GetInputStream()`. Aclually my document generation engine is pretty complex. I have rtf template and logo image (which is dynamically inserted in rtf during generation) in the database... so, I resolved my issue by creating a new CF context for the purpose of the doc generation _> `GetInputStream(cf, 0, 0)`. @meziantou

Comment: As you've disabled blob caching, `GetInputStream` returns a `DataReaderStream` instead of a `FileStream`, and doesn't call `CompleteCommand`. Even if you create a new context, I think you should call `CompleteCommand` after reading the stream to clean up resources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what actually worked for me:

```
public byte[] GetRtfDocumentStreamBuffer(TemplateDocumentType templateType, int culture)
{
    var template = TemplateDocument.LoadActiveByDocumentTypeAndLcid(DateTime.Today, templateType.Id, culture);
    var resultStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var cf = CodeFluentContext.GetNew(Constants.MyApplicationStoreName))
    using (var templateStream = template.File.GetInputStream(cf, 0, 0))
    using (var resultWriter = new StreamWriter(resultStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")))
    {
        GenerateRtfDocument(....);

        resultWriter.Flush();
    }

    return resultStream.GetBuffer();
}
```

what I saw in decompiled cf runtime that is `CodeFluentContext.Dispose()` call `CodeFluentPersistence.Dispose()` which close reader and dispose connection.